# Django commit manually doesn't manage django QuerySet.update()?

Tags: django, transactions

Django `QuerySet.update` doesn't deal with `transaction.commit_manually`, and commit automatically.

I built a customized django view like this...

#### class Foo(View)

```
@method_decorator(transaction.commit_manually)
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        Model.objects.all().update(rank=10)
        data_to_update = resquest.
        for d in data_to_update:
            model = Model.objects.get(pk=d['id'])
            model.rank = d['rank']
            model.save()
        transaction.commit()
        status_code = 200
    except Exception, e:
        # do some stuff
        transaction.rollback()
        status_code = 500

    return HttpResponse(content='Foo', status=status_code)
```

... and if any expection is raised after the `Model.objects.all().update(rank=10)`,
the `transaction.rollback()` doesn't work properly, and all models I'll have rank setted to 10.
I don't know why it happens, and i can't iterate by all models and call save method to each one(performance reasons).

Comment: Which DB backend are you using? Not all of the available backends support transactions.

Comment: Postgres and transaction manually works if i use ...
for music in all_musics:                                          
    music.ranking = 0                                             
    music.save()
instead of Model.objects.all().update().

Comment: If true that sounds like a bug. The looking at the source it does not appear to commit the transaction if otherwise managed on an update: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/query.py#L543

Comment: maybe! but i still hope that i'll found a way to do it. big thanks buddy!